# QGIS connection to ArcGIS Online account with credentials

Tags: qgis

Am I able to make a connection in QGIS to my ArcGIS Online account to pull services I have published to the account?  None of these services are shared publicly so they would need credentials to access.  I see all the options for entering authentication parameters.  I am just not sure which one I need to use and where I find the information for filling it out.

Comment: Hi, there is nice article at this link - https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-add-data-from-arcgis-online-to-qgis/ . Basically you need to copy url of your service (using server or portal) and then paste it in 'Add ArcGIS Rest Service Layer' qgis window. You fill authentication values with your username/email and pass and it should load the data.

Comment: I didn't try but this tutorial seem to cover it all : https://north-road.com/2022/09/16/securely-accessing-arcgis-online-agol-and-enterprise-arcgis-portal-sites-through-qgis-2022-update/